# Internal Server Error 500 when downloading a large zip file

Tags: php, file, download, zip, internal-server-error

I have a program that lets me choose files to download. Once the files have been chosen, the files are put in a zip file and the zip is downloaded. After a certain size around 500MB I get an Internal Server Error, but it works with no issues for sizes that are not as big.

I have already made the memory_limit 4096MB and the max_execution_time to 3600. display_errors is also enabled but it does not show anything. The error_log is empty as well.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();    
$zip_name = "generated_zips/".time().".zip";  
$zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);  
foreach ($file_ids as $file) {  
    if ($file != ""){  
        $db_file = get_file($file);
        if($db_file['isTiff']==1){
            $path = $db_file['file_dir_tiff'];
        }
        else{
            $path = $db_file['file_dir'];
        }
        $zip->addFromString(basename($path), file_get_contents($path));
        $zip->renameName(basename($path), $db_file['fileName']);
    }
}
$zip->close();
if (file_exists($zip_name)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zip_name');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_name));
    readfile($zip_name);
    ob_clean();
    ob_end_flush();
    unlink($zip_name);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: depending on download speed, you may need to adjust the execution time, depends on many things though, are the files POSTed? you may need to adjust post settings too

Comment: check it on the server side too.

Comment: check the error log because if the debugging is disabled by default it will show the 500 page